# Passing multiple expressions as a variable to sed command then output to new file

Tags: bash

I am reading some configs from a text file and storing them into a variable.  THey are pipe separated like this:

```
a,b|c,d|e,f|g,h
```

I want to pass these into a sed command to substitute the left value from the right value in a text file and output that to another file.

I have:

```
#!/bin/bash
test="a,b|c,d|e,f|j,l"
arr=(`echo $test | sed 's/|/\n/g'`)
sub=""
for i in "${arr[@]}"
do
   echo "$i"
    array=(`echo $i | sed 's/,/\n/g'`)
    sub+="s/${array[0]}/${array[1]}/g; "
done

sed $sub ${FILE} > output.json
```

When I do this it runs a sed command for each element in arr.  So after the first sed it says:

```
No such file or directory
```

Now if I don't pass in $sub as a variable and just put the entire string in it does it in one sed command and it works:

```
sed "s/a/b/g; s/c/d/g; s/e/f/g; s/g/h/g;" ${FILE} > output.json
```

How can I pass in my matchers as a variable like in my first example, but get it to do it all in one sed command like the second example?

Comment: `var='a,b|c,d|e,f|g,h'; var="${var//,//}"; var="${var//|//g; s/}"; sed "s/${var}/g" "$file"`

Comment: There are many problems with your script - check your scripts with https://shellcheck.net

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> How can I pass in my matchers as a variable like in my first example, but get it to do it all in one sed command like the second example?

Shellcheck will hint you:

```
Line 12:
sed $sub ${FILE} > output.json
    ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.
         ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Did you mean: (apply this, apply all SC2086)
sed "$sub" "${FILE}" > output.json
```

Because there is a space after `;` the pattern is word splitted. Quote it to prevent expansion. When `$sub` is not quoted, the `s/c/d/g;` is parsed as a filename, so `sed` exits with no such file or directory.